# `childMarkdownRemark` not appearing in GraphiQL Schema

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Good afternoon! I'm currently working on a blog application (using Gatsby & Contentful) - everything was progressing as I anticipated until I ran into a bit of a problem rendering the body of my Contentful blog in HTML as opposed to JSON. Specifically the query I'm working with is this:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($pathSlug: String!) {
    contentfulBlog(path: { eq: $pathSlug }) {
      author
      title
      excerpt
      path
      body {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The name of the field I'd like to render as html is currently in JSON. When I attempt `gatsby build`, the error I get is the following:

```
Cannot query field "childMarkdownRemark" on type "contentfulBlogBodyRichTextNode".
```

I'm incredibly confused as to why this field isn't available to me through GraphiQL and have gone through various starter projects to confirm that it should be an available field with Contentful. I'm able to see the contents of every other field I pass through perfectly, for example the post's author.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Here's a screenshot of my schema - I'd expect to see `childMarkdownRemark` included but am not seeing it.

[image: schema]

Comment: Do you have `gatsby-transformer-remark` installed?

Comment: @ksav I have checked that - what's strange is that I spun up one of the gatsby contentful starter repos & connected it to the contentful blog content I set up and I see `childMarkdownRemark` appear.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but did you remember to include the plugin into your gatsby-config.js? That is what happened to me